# Is there any way to load html content in chrome custom tab

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs, android-customtabs

Is it possible to load local html content using chrome custom tab in android? I searched the web, could not find the solution, can anyone help..

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to directly load HTML content using Chrome Custom Tabs but you could try saving the content to a local file and providing a file:// URL to see if that works.